# Find pattern and replace it by "Prestring" + pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

Hi I have a `DataFrame` with column `Text` which contains strings. What I want to do is to find my pattern:

`pattern = "Car:" + "|".join(["Audi", "Toyota"])`

and simply change `Car` to `MyCar` for those findings (Toyota and Audi). How can I do that for the entire `df`?

Input:
`pd.DataFrame("Text": ["ThisIsCar:Audi", "ThisIsCar:BMW"])`

Output:
`pd.DataFrame("Text": ["ThisIsMyCar:Audi", "ThisIsCar:BMW"])`

Comment: What's the input and expected output?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I added Input and Output

Comment: How about replace [`Car:(?=Audi|Toyota)`](https://regex101.com/r/6KLvy7/1) with `MyCar:`